# Unexpected logoff in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

Currently I have a problem with my IIS and it is that some users have informed me that their session is closed in a way unexpected in the web application, even before the configured timeout which is 15 minutes. The application that runs is on .net framework 4.6 and the database is sql server 2016. You have already checked the performance of the web server and the database but you do not see the saturation of RAM or CPU consumption or I have seen errors in the event viewer. Reciclyng is set to take place daily at 3:00 am. Anything you can suggest me to validate either on the servers or on the clients?

I have reviewed the timeout values in the webconfig, but here the value in minutes is 15.
Also I have seen logs and event viewer , but i didn't find anything that can are generating the problem.

Comment: Even though you mentioned SQL Server in the question body, did you check what's the session mode used by your ASP.NET 4.x web app? I think it still uses in-process mode and forms authentication, right?

Comment: Try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool may generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Hi Lex, I reviewed the autentication for this site and currently we have active anonymus and forms autentication.

Comment: Capturing and analyzing dump files is a good option if you haven't been able to get useful error messages.

Comment: Thanks @samwu . I captured the dump with help to IIS debug diagnostics but after to do the analisys, this no generated any error in the report. Do you know any tools that allow me capture logs with more details?

Comment: This link should help you: [How to use the Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-high-cpu-usage-by-a-process-in-iis-636559d3-2f31-71eb-d2ba-75da26ece9d7).